# "onclick" attribute in anchor element inside react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to create a react component which should render a tree of nodes, in which one of the element is supposed to be an anchor. The JSX would be:

```
return(
  <div>
    <span>.....</span>
    <a href="someurl" onclick="javascript:....."
    ...somemore element
  </div>
);
```

I want to add an aatribute "onclick" to the anchor element. How can i achieve it? I don't want to use onClick method of reactJS, which is equivalent to addEventListner method. I want to define it as attribute to anchor, so that it should appear as below in html dom tree:

```
<a href=".." onclick="javascript:..."
```

Comment: As long as it doesn't need to reference any variables local to the class you're instantiating it from, it might be possible. If it does need to access local variables, it's probably entirely impossible

Answer (score 1):

This won't work with React as it will not pass a regular `onclick` attribute through. It also makes no sense, as the recommended `onClick` can do all the same things.

```
<a href="..." onClick={() => alert('hello')}>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const html = '<a onclick="javascript:alert(2)">bbb</a>';
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I used this code here: https://playcode.io/react and it worked. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` allows you to set the html raw, but I think it requires a parent DOM element, like the div above. I don't know if you can do it without a parent element to set the html of.